# AngularJS does not work on Adobe AEM CQ T&T

Tags: angularjs, aem, mbox

I am facing a unique scenario, when an experience is set up on a component using Target, the page breaks. Issue is because the components for which an experience has been set up is loaded through ajax using AEM's internal javascript libraries. AS the angular app is already instantiated the dynamically injected components are not compiled and all the angularJS syntax shows up on the page when it breaks. Angular Bootsrapping is also not possible as the dom is injected by AEM's internal javscript, not sure when to call bootstrap method.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue if anyone has faced it before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Angular apps, but I can tell you that the use-case you are describing it's not supported with AEM (others have complained). The main problem is the one that you described - the Target client-library (mbox.js) loads the content asynchronously (using mboxUpdate() ) calls. 
However, I don't know if this is necessarily an AEM issue - are you able to use targeted content with mbox.js and Angular without AEM?

What version of AEM are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am using AEM 6.1, is there any callback functions or any events which is available after all the mboxUpdate calls are completed so that I can bootstrap the application using this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The mbox functions don't provide any callback support, but you can work around this by using a "plugin offer" in Adobe Target - it's an HTML offer which is included with every offer delivery.